# Dynamically replace a text element of an svg object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to dynamically replace a text element of an svg object from a local text file. Below my files text et svg:

text file:

```
<p id="p1">It works fine</p>
```

text svg:

```
<svg width="640" height="480" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<rect id="svg_1" height="87" width="162" y="188" x="130" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-width="5" stroke="blue" fill="yellow"/>
<text xml:space="preserve" text-anchor="start" font-family="serif" font-size="24" id="divA" y="240" x="313" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-width="0" stroke="#000000" fill="blue"> </text>
</svg>
```

It works fine with the div or if I put the value, for example dog, for the element svg to modify. below mon fichier html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        var x = $("#divA").load("demo_test.txt #p1");
        var y = $("#div1").load("demo_test.txt #p1");
        document.getElementById("div1").textContent = y;
        var svg = document.getElementById("textsvg");
        var svgDoc = svg.contentDocument;
        svgDoc.getElementById("divA").textContent = "dog";                
         });               
    </script>
 </head>
<body>
        <div id="div1"><h2>PSU0 to PDU-A G0-2</h2></div>
        <object id="textsvg" width="600" height="480" type="image/svg+xml" data="essai.svg"></object>     
</body>
```

However, when I put the variable y for the text element svg I have the message "[object Object]" instead of the message "It works fine". Below the html file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        var x = $("#divA").load("demo_test.txt #p1");
        var y = $("#div1").load("demo_test.txt #p1");
        document.getElementById("div1").textContent = y;
        var svg = document.getElementById("textsvg");
        var svgDoc = svg.contentDocument;
        svgDoc.getElementById("divA").textContent = x;                
         });               
    </script>
 </head>
<body>
        <div id="div1"><h2>PSU0 to PDU-A G0-2</h2></div>
        <object id="textsvg" width="600" height="480" type="image/svg+xml" data="essai.svg"></object>     
</body>
```

Can you help me.

Thanks,

B.R,

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#divA").html("Gorillaz Inc");
     });               
</script>
```

This works with jquery

Full example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pRRgaP

Note: I didn't use files, I just updated the svg dynamically

Comment: Thanks for your help but my html works fine from local file text with div and a string of character for element svg to modify but does not work with element svg to modify from local text file

Answer (score 0):

I solved part of my problem. I have directly embedded the "svg" into my html.
I noticed that by downloading the text file without the tags: demo_text1.txt the div appears well and the text svg:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#div1").load("demo_test.txt #p2");
    $("#divA").load("demo_test1.txt");
      });               
  </script>
 </head>
<body>
    <div id="div1"><h2 style="color:blue">PSU0 to PDU-A G0-2</h2></div>

    <svg width="800" height="480" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect id="svg_1" height="87" width="162" y="20" x="5" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-width="5" stroke="blue" fill="yellow"/>
    <text xml:space="preserve" text-anchor="start" font-family="serif" font-size="14" id="divA" y="67" x="175" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-width="0" stroke="#000000" fill="blue"> </text>
    </svg>   
</body>
</html>
```

fichier text:demo_test.txt

```
<p id="p1" >It works fine</p>
<p id="p2" style="color:blue">I use the local text file "demo_test.txt".The "div" works fine with tags</p>
```

fichier text:demo_text1.txt

```
I use the local text file "demo_test1.txt". 
The text of svg works fine without tag but doesn't work with tags
```

Screen display ok:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uCm3.png)

However, by pointing the text svg to the text file with the tags (demo_test.txt, it does not work:

Screen not ok:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFKa9.png)